# Bidirectional UDP Multicast

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp, multicast

I am writing a network backend for a game server.

I planned on using multicast, so that clients could bind to the server via a multicast socket. The server could then send game updates to all members of the group.

I'm wondering, however, if it's possible to do the **reverse** — can clients send unicast data to the server, *over the same port as the multicast socket*?

I've written a test program based off of the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html) (which only sends server —> client), but I was unable to adapt that to bidirectional communication. I'm getting `Address already in use` and `Not a multicast address` errors on the client.

Are my suspicions correct that such bidirectional communications are not possible using the same port? Must I use different ports (one for multicast [server —> clients], one for unicast [clients —> server])?

(I'm doing this in Java, but I'm more interested in the network-side-of-things *is this possible* vs. implementation-side *how do I do this*.)

Comment: Multicast is uni-directional (server -> clients).  The server cannot use the same bound IP:Port pair to receive data, it must use a different IP:Port pair.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Where did you get that idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

Suppose a server with IP address 192.168.1.2 wants to send multicast messages to 224.1.2.3 port 2222 and receive unicast resposes back on port 1111.  On the server side, bind a datagram socket to address/port 0.0.0.0:1111.  On the client side, bind the datagram socket to 0.0.0.0:2222, then register the socket for multicast group 224.1.2.3.  The server has the option to specify 192.168.1.2 when binding its local port, but is not required.  The client must bind to 0.0.0.0, otherwise multicast packets can't be received on Linux systems.

When the server wants to send, it specifies both the message and the IP/port of the destination.  In this case, the server uses its datagram socket to send to 224.1.2.3:2222, although you can later send to a different address/port if you wish.  The resulting packet has a source IP/port of 192.168.1.2:1111 and a destination IP/port of 224.1.2.3:2222.

For the client to send back to the server, it specifies both the message and the IP/port of the destination, which in this case is 192.168.1.2:1111.  So the resulting packet has a source IP/port of {client_IP}:2222 and a destination port of 192.168.1.2:1111.  Only one socket on the server and one socket on each client are required.

Comment: I see. My mistake was that I was trying to bind the multicast socket to the server itself, not an arbitrary multicast group.

Comment: (also I wanted to have a single port, not one for sending and one for receiving)

Comment: Using the same port number for the client and server shouldn't be an issue, so long as they aren't running on the same machine.

Comment: Allowing the server to use the same local port number for sending and receiving. Though I guess that doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

> can clients send unicast data to the server, over the same port as the multicast socket?

Yes, as long as the socket isn't bound to the multicast address. Apparently Linux requires this, but other platforms let you bind it to 0.0.0.0.

Note that what you're asking about isn't 'bidirectional multicast'. It is multicast in one direction, and unicast in the other.

Comment: But the server *is* using multicast for the other direction.

Comment: @baum The server doesn't have to *bind* to the multicast address to do that. Except, apparently, on Linux, for reasons which I have never understood. It doesn't even have to join the multicast group. Only the multicast receivers (the clients) need to do that.

Comment: I should correct that. The sender doesn't need to bind at all. It is the *receivers* that may need to bind to the multicast address.