# Socket broadcast basics

Tags: sockets

I am building an application that will deploy in effect on multiple "clients" with a common "server". Clearly I could communicate between each client and the server using a single read-write socket for each client-server link, or a read socket and a write socket per link if I really wanted to.

But what if there are (hopefully good) reasons that the server wants to read from any client, and broadcast back to all? If you have a connectionless protocol like UDP, can the server use only a single read-write socket, or must it use one for reading and one for writing? What about the clients? And does this change if you use a connection-based protocol like TCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you have a connectionless protocol like UDP, can the server use only a single read-write socket, or must it use one for reading and one for writing? What about the clients? And does this change if you use a connection-based protocol like TCP?

A socket as an endpoint which has at least a local address and port in case of UDP and TCP. Only data received for this ip and port are delivered to the socket and all data send from this socket contain the local ip and port as the source. A socket can be connected, in which case also the destination IP and port is known. With TCP a socket needs to be connected, with UDP not.

This means:

- You can use the same unconnected UDP socket to send data to multiple peers (destination is an argument for the sendto function). You cannot do this with TCP, i.e. you need a connected socket for each single peer.
- You can receive data from multiple peers on an unconnected UDP socket. You cannot do this with TCP.
- The special broadcast address can be used with UDP but not with TCP, since with TCP you need to have a connection between only two clients which is not the case with broadcast.

See also a related question with answer for more information: [Bidirectional UDP Multicast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30315109/bidirectional-udp-multicast)

Answer (score 1):

> But what if there are (hopefully good) reasons that the server wants
>   to read from any client, and broadcast back to all?

Well, then you'd probably want to use a UDP socket (either instead of, or in addition to, some TCP sockets) :)

> If you have a connectionless protocol like UDP, can the server use
>   only a single read-write socket, or must it use one for reading and
>   one for writing?

A single UDP socket is sufficient for both reading and writing (although some multithreaded designs might find it easier to use two separate sockets instead; either way will work).

> What about the clients?

Clients can also use a single socket for both sending and receive UDP packets, if that's what you're asking.

> And does this change if you use a connection-based protocol like TCP?

With TCP sockets you can also use a single socket for both sending and receiving.  However you will need one TCP socket for each destination that you want to send or receive to/from.  (Contrast this with UDP where a single UDP socket can be used in conjunction with sendto() or recvfrom() to communicate with multiple peers)

Answer (score -2):

As per your requirement, you have two ways :

1. **By using TCP connection only** : Server reads message from client and for the broadcasting to all clients,server writes message to all client's TCP sockets(connected to clients) and clients read that message from TCP socket(connected to server).This method requires that client and server knows the IP addresses of each other
2. **By using TCP connection for the client-server direct communication and UDP for broadcasting** : In this method,client and server communicates (directly one to one) using TCP connection. For broadcasting the message, server can broadcast the message over the network using UDP socket and clients have UDP broadcast receiver for receiving the broadcast message.

Comment: Are you truly saying there is no way to use UDP for everything? That seems unlikely to me. I'd like to know why not if that's truly the case.

Comment: As we know that UDP is connectionless (less reliable) while the TCP is connection oriented (more reliable). You can also define the destination IP in UDP packet for specific target but it is connectionless and not so much reliable. UDP is mostly used when destination is unknown. When destination is known, it is preferable to use TCP because it is much reliable. You can do you work with UDP only but it not so much reliable so i suggest you to use both TCP and UDP.

Comment: Lots of things are wrong here, among them "UDP is mostly used when destination is unknown". UDP is used for real-time audio and video like in VoIP scenarios, is used for DNS, syslog, ... The destination is always known, but it might be a broadcast destination where multiple systems can receive. But mostly UDP is used with a single destination, like TCP.

Comment: TCP doesn't require that the server knows the address of the client. UDP *cannot* be used when the destination is unknown, unless you're talking about broadcast or multicast.